# log4net AdoNetAppender RawTimeStampLayout with no millsecond

Tags: log4net, adonetappender

I have AdoNetAppender, I use the RawTimeStampLayout but no millsecond

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value=":LOG_DATETIME" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
```

I want to know how to get the millseconds in the element.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your miliseconds are lost when you save it into the database. Check if your LOG_Datetime column has the right type: datetime or datetime2. If not it can lose the miliseconds.